# run sql file with input from python

Tags: python, plsql

I have a .sql file which gets an input and runs, I should run it from a python code with some inputs, but it doesn't work. What is problem?

sql file:

```
declare
  --define variables
   v_workspace_id NUMBER;

BEGIN

  select workspace_id into v_workspace_id
  from apex_workspaces
  where workspace = upper('&1');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_workspace_id);

  apex_application_install.set_workspace_id( v_workspace_id );
  apex_application_install.generate_application_id;
  apex_application_install.generate_offset;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS    
    THEN
            RAISE;

END;
```

part of python file to run this file:

```
cmd_sql = 'echo quit | sqlplus -S ' + DB_USER + '/' + DB_USER_PWD + '@' + DB_HOST + ' @' + SQL_PATH + '\\' + 'install_apex_apps.sql ' + user_name + ' >> ' + LOG_FILE
os.system(cmd_sql)
```

user_name is given as an input to sql file.

Comment: I believe @davidm is correct, but I would add one more thing (more correctly remove one thing). Get rid of the EXCEPTION handler.  It does nothing  that you would not get if it simply does not exist. but it does mislead you. For example as error occurs in the function `generate_application_id` your exception handler the resulting error message indicate the` raise` statement, not the point where the error occurred. Without the exception handler  in would point to the line in `generate_application_id`

Comment: If your organization standard requires the exception handler then at lease look into [FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73241) and [FORMAT_ERROR_STACK](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73242) for your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PL/SQL

Change code to (note the `/`). Also as @Belayer sugessted in the comment section remove the `EXCEPTION` section.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
  --define variables
   v_workspace_id NUMBER;

BEGIN

  select workspace_id into v_workspace_id
  from apex_workspaces
  where workspace = upper('&1');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_workspace_id);

  apex_application_install.set_workspace_id( v_workspace_id );
  apex_application_install.generate_application_id;
  apex_application_install.generate_offset;

END;
/
```

#### Python

##### Linux

```py
import os

DB_USER = 'xxx'
DB_USER_PWD = 'xxx'
DB_HOST = 'xxx'
SQL_PATH = '/home/xxx/Documents/stack/'

LOG_FILE = '/home/xxx/Documents/stack/log.txt'

user_name = 'xxx'

# I override the log file with > for appending use >>
cmd_sql = 'echo quit | sqlplus -S ' + DB_USER + '/' + DB_USER_PWD + '@' + DB_HOST + ' @' + SQL_PATH + 'install_apex_apps.sql ' + user_name + ' > ' + LOG_FILE
os.system(cmd_sql)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but my problem is that these 3 commands don't run without any error to recognize the reason. 



      `apex_application_install.set_workspace_id( v_workspace_id );
       apex_application_install.generate_application_id;
       apex_application_install.generate_offset;`

Comment: there is not eny error, just dosn't work.

Comment: What should your script do?

Comment: You asked *...I should run it from a python code with some inputs, but it doesn't work...*

Comment: the goal for whole this script its to install an apex application, when I run all scripts from toad everything is ok, but when I run it from python, it is such that some parts dosnt't work and I get errors in next steps. fro example if 3 command that I just mentioned , run correct, the next step that is installing an apex application should run without error, but i see errors which means these parts didn't run correctly.

Comment: Check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/INSTALL-Procedure.html#GUID-D44BDEE9-C249-4984-987E-55F1DABD6B03). My answer does what you asked.